# Datatable not apply on dynamically created table using MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I am having issue with datatable in mvc application mvc has one common layout that is master page (**Layout Page**)

I have implement datatable commonly in master page (**Layout page**) that apply to all child pages

now , I am stuck with one challenge that is some tables are created dynamically on comobo box selection

**Layout Page**

```
$('.table').DataTable({
        "aoColumnDefs": [
                          {
                              bSortable: false,
                              aTargets: [-1], /* 1st one, start by the right */
                              "defaultContent": "",
                          }
        ],
        "fixedHeader": true,
        "lengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "responsive": true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "scrollY": "300px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging": false,
        initComplete: function (settings, json) {
            this.api().columns().header().each(function (th) {
                $(th).removeClass("sorting_asc");
                $(th).removeClass("sorting");
            }
         )
        },
    });
```

**Child (Partial View)**

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <br />
                    <div id="example"></div>                        
                </div>
            </div>

function GetEmails() {
        var tbl = $('#example');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/GetTestData',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);                
        }).error(function (result) {
            alert("Fail");
        });
    }
```

Now , I have issue that

```
 tbl.empty().append(result);
```

after append table in div , datatable not apply on this table, I am wondering that how can I able to notify in **Layout page** that table is append in **child** page

Let me know , there is any event in javascript or jquery that fire after append or something ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to initialise it in your success, after you append the result: `tbl.find('.table').DataTable(... options)`

Comment: That success event not fire in layout page, it's only work in partial view (child view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
Its working

```
function ApplyDataTable()
{      
$('#example').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (event) {
    if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted') 
    {
    //Datatable for search and sorting
    $(currntTable).DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
                      {
                          bSortable: false,
                          aTargets: [-1], /* 1st one, start by the right */
                          "defaultContent": "",
                      }
    ],
    "fixedHeader": true,
    "lengthChange": false,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "responsive": true,
    "autoWidth": false,
    "scrollY": "300px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    });      
    } 
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize datatable in success of ajax something like this,

```
  $('.Table').DataTable();
```

But if you really want to add the datatable from layout only, then this should be helpful

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, settings) {
        $('.Table').DataTable();
    });
```

Comment: It's not working in layout page, it's only work with partial (child) page